# command in cron to run php every certain mins

Tags: php, cron

this might be a repeat.
i would like to run my index.php every certain mins. My server has option run cron command/ cron jobs. Someone please tell me what could should I use to schedule.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *why*?

Second, `crontab -e` will allow you to edit your crontab.  Then it's just as easy as

```
? * * * * php /path/to/index.php
```

Comment: Why use a php-script through cron? Cleanup-DB, send mails from stack, resize uploaded images, ...

Comment: @Ron he says "my index.php" -- I assume that means the web root

Comment: I want to update some links that are variable based on other sites.

Comment: php /home/streaml1/public_html/test.php worked perfectly...thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You could use this command

```
Minutes Hours  Day  Month WeekDay
45      *      *    *     *        php /path/to/index.php *
```

Here is an [article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) about a php cron manager

Answer (score 0):

First, here is how cron works:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Then, the comand should look like this:

`* * * * * cd /directory/of/the/script/ && php scriptname.php >> /directory/of/the/logfile.log`